# Distribution of the initializing set at K-means++

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, k-means, gaussian-mixture-distribution

There is a well-known modification of the initializing step of K-means, named K-means++. It chooses cluster centers with [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) proportional to its squared distance from the point's closest existing cluster center.

If the data are coming from a mixture distribution of normals, what is the distribution of the cluster centers after the initializing step?